# Detect specific format of version number using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking to extract elements of an array containing a version number, where a version number is either at the start or end of a string or padded by spaces, and is a series of digits and periods but does not start or end with a period. For example "10.10 Thingy" and "Thingy 10.10.5" is valid, but "Whatever 4" is not.

```
haystack = ["10.10 Thingy", "Thingy 10.10.5", "Whatever 4", "Whatever 4.x"]
haystack.select{ |i| i[/(?<=^| )(\d+)(\.\d+)*(?=$| )/] }
=> ["10.10 Thingy", "Thingy 10.10.5", "Whatever 4"]
```

I'm not sure how to modify the regex to require at least one period so that "Whatever 4" is not in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a slight variant of Archonic's answer.

```
r = /
    (?<=\A|\s) # match the beginning of the string or a space in a positive lookbehind
    (?:\d+\.)+ # match >= 1 digits followed by a period in a non-capture group, >= 1 times 
    \d+        # match >= 1 digits
    (?=\s|\z)  # match a space or the end of the string in a positive lookahead
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

haystack = ["10.10 Thingy", "Thingy 10.10.5", "Whatever 4", "Whatever 4.x"]

haystack.select { |str| str =~ r }
  #=> ["10.10 Thingy", "Thingy 10.10.5"]
```

The question was not to return the version information, but to to return the strings that have correct version information. As a result there is no need for the lookarounds:

```
r = /
    [\A\s\]    # match the beginning of the string or a space
    (?:\d+\.)+ # match >= 1 digits followed by a period in a non-capture group, >= 1 times 
    \d+        # match >= 1 digits
    [\s\z]     # match a space or the end of the string in a positive lookahead
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

haystack.select { |str| str =~ r }
  #=> ["10.10 Thingy", "Thingy 10.10.5"]
```

Suppose one wanted to obtain both the strings that contain valid versions and the versions contained in those strings. One could write the following:

```
r = /
    (?<=\A|\s\) # match the beginning of string or a space in a pos lookbehind
    (?:\d+\.)+  # match >= 1 digits then a period in non-capture group, >= 1 times 
    \d+         # match >= 1 digits
    (?=\s|\z)   # match a space or end of string in a pos lookahead
    /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode

haystack.each_with_object({}) do |str,h|
  version = str[r]
  h[str] = version if version
end
  # => {"10.10 Thingy"=>"10.10", "Thingy 10.10.5"=>"10.10.5"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail!

Answer (score 1):

Ah hah! I knew I was close.

`haystack.select{ |i| i[/(?<=^| )(\d+)(\.\d+)+(?=$| )/] }`

The asterisk at the end of `(\.\d+)*` was allowing that pattern to repeat any number of times, including zero times. You can limit that with `(\.\d+){x,y}` where x and y are the min and max times. You can also only identify a minimum with `(\.\d+){x,}`. In my case I wanted a minimum of once, which would be `(\.\d+){1,}`, however that's synonymous with `(\.\d+)+`. That only took half the day to figure out...